# How to convert csv to nested beans using OpenCSV or any other library?

Tags: java, csv, parsing, opencsv

I'm making an HTTP call to get an CSV file and I'm using OpenCSV to convert string equivalent of CSV file to plain old java object. I have skipped the logic to make http call to fetch csv since it had sensitive information. The converted Student object from the below code has null values for "collegeTiming" property. How to map this value from CSV ? Can someone please suggest? Thanks in advance!

PFB my dependency in pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
        <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
        <version>4.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

My Input CSV

```
"id", "name", "monday_open_time", "monday_close_time", "tuesday_open_time", "tuesday_close_time", "wednesday_open_time", "wednesday_close_time", "thursday_open_time", "thrusday_close_time", "friday_open_time", "friday_close_time"
1, ABCD, 07.00.00,21.00.00, 08.00.00,22.00.00, 07.00.00,21.00.00, 07.00.00,21.00.00, 07.00.00,21.00.00
2, ABCD, 08.00.00,21.00.00, 07.00.00,14.00.00, 07.00.00,21.00.00, 07.00.00,21.00.00, 07.00.00,21.00.00
3, ABCD, 07.00.00,21.00.00, 10.00.00,13.00.00, 07.00.00,21.00.00, 07.00.00,21.00.00, 07.00.00,21.00.00
4, ABCD, 09.00.00,21.00.00, 11.00.00,20.00.00, 07.00.00,21.00.00, 07.00.00,21.00.00, 07.00.00,21.00.00
```

I want to convert the input csv to below Student bean

```
{
    "id" : 1,
    "name": ABC,
    "collegeTime" : { 
                        "monday":[ 07.00.00, 21.00.00 ], 
                        "tuesday":[ 08.00.00, 22.00.00 ], 
                        "wednesday":[ 07.00.00, 21.00.00 ], 
                        "thrusday":[ 07.00.00, 21.00.00 ], 
                        "friday":[ 07.00.00, 21.00.00 ], 
                        }

}
```

Student.java

```
import java.util.List;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.opencsv.bean.CsvBindByName;

public class Student {
@CsvBindByName
@JsonProperty("id")
private String id;
@JsonProperty("name")
@CsvBindByName
private String name;
@JsonProperty("collegeTiming")
private List<CollegeTiming> collegeTimings;

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public List<CollegeTiming> getCollegeTimings() {
    return collegeTimings;
}

public void setCollegeTimings(List<CollegeTiming> collegeTimings) {
    this.collegeTimings = collegeTimings;
}
}
```

CollegeTiming.java

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

public class CollegeTiming {
@JsonProperty("collegeTime")    
private CollegeTime collegeTime;

public CollegeTime getCollegeTime() {
    return collegeTime;
}

public void setCollegeTime(CollegeTime collegeTime) {
    this.collegeTime = collegeTime;
}
}
```

CollegeTime.java

```
public class CollegeTime {
private String day;
private String startTime;
private String endTime;

public String getStartTime() {
    return startTime;
}

public void setStartTime(String startTime) {
    this.startTime = startTime;
}

public String getEndTime() {
    return endTime;
}

public void setEndTime(String endTime) {
    this.endTime = endTime;
}   

}
```

//Converting csv to Student object using OpenCSV. 
Note: csvAsString is string representation of csv file (I made a HTTP call to fetch this information.

```
 HeaderColumnNameMappingStrategy<Student> strategy = new HeaderColumnNameMappingStrategy<>();
    strategy.setType(Student.class);

CsvToBean<Student> csvToBean = new CsvToBeanBuilder<Student>(new StringReader(csvAsString))
             .withType(Student.class)
             .withMappingStrategy(strategy)
             .withIgnoreLeadingWhiteSpace(true)
             .build();

 List<Student> = = csvToBean.parse();
```

When I print the Student object, null is getting printed for "collegeTiming" property of Student object. How to map the csv file to nested object (CollegeTime) ?

Answer (score 0):

This seems a bit odd, you are trying to push flat data into a hierarchy. You will need to do some custom processing there since your keys also do not match the model you are trying to build. I have made an example on how to achieve that using the `CSVReader` and Jackson's `ObjectMapper`:

```
public class CSVMappingTest {

    static String csv = "\"id\", \"name\", \"monday_open_time\", \"monday_close_time\", \"tuesday_open_time\", \"tuesday_close_time\", \"wednesday_open_time\", \"wednesday_close_time\", \"thursday_open_time\", \"thrusday_close_time\", \"friday_open_time\", \"friday_close_time\"\n" + 
            "1, ABCD, 07.00.00,21.00.00, 08.00.00,22.00.00, 07.00.00,21.00.00, 07.00.00,21.00.00, 07.00.00,21.00.00\n" + 
            "2, ABCD, 08.00.00,21.00.00, 07.00.00,14.00.00, 07.00.00,21.00.00, 07.00.00,21.00.00, 07.00.00,21.00.00\n" + 
            "3, ABCD, 07.00.00,21.00.00, 10.00.00,13.00.00, 07.00.00,21.00.00, 07.00.00,21.00.00, 07.00.00,21.00.00\n" + 
            "4, ABCD, 09.00.00,21.00.00, 11.00.00,20.00.00, 07.00.00,21.00.00, 07.00.00,21.00.00, 07.00.00,21.00.00";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new StringReader(csv));
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        String[] keys = reader.readNext(); // headers
        String[] values = reader.readNext();
        while(values != null) {
            Student convertValue = mapper.convertValue(csvToMap(keys, values), Student.class);
            System.err.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(convertValue));
            values = reader.readNext();
        }
    }

    public static Map<String, String> csvToMap(final String[] headers, final String[] vals) {
        if(headers == null || vals == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("Empty input for csv to map");
        }
        if(headers.length != vals.length) { 
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Header and value count do not match for csv to map");
        }
        Map<String, String> res = new HashMap<>();
        IntStream.range(0, vals.length).forEach( i -> res.put(headers[i], vals[i]));
        return res;
    }

    public static class Student { 
        @JsonProperty("id")
        String id;
        @JsonProperty("name")
        String name;
        @JsonProperty
        Map<String, String> studentTimings = new HashMap<>();

        @JsonAnySetter
        public void setTime(String key, String value) { 
            studentTimings.put(key, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Explanations:

I only use the `CSVReader` to retrieve a row.

I then use a `csvToMap` to create a mapping of header-value.

I then use the convertion method on jackson to auto-create the bean i want.

The important bit is here:

```
    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setTime(String key, String value) { 
        studentTimings.put(key, value);
    }
```

This tells jackson that any property not directly wrapped will be send here. 
This is where you would process your times and manually group them into whatever buckets you want. I do not see any other alternative since your flat input does not match the properties you are trying to create.

Neither OpenCSV nor Jackson are processors. They are not responsible for transforming your data, their purpose is as simple as "find the key and call the setter". You can use custom serialiser of any form in order to tell it how to create the objects you want, but the default is as simple as the statement above.

I am sure there is an OpenCSV method for this as well, however I don't know it :)

I hope that helps,

Artur

P.s. i did not copy your entire model but rather just pushed the values into a map. The output of my parsing would then be for example:

```
{
  "id": "3",
  "name": " ABCD",
  "studentTimings": {
    "friday_close_time": "21.00.00",
    "friday_open_time": " 07.00.00",
    "monday_close_time": "21.00.00",
    "monday_open_time": " 07.00.00",
    "thrusday_close_time": "21.00.00",
    "thursday_open_time": " 07.00.00",
    "tuesday_close_time": "13.00.00",
    "tuesday_open_time": " 10.00.00",
    "wednesday_close_time": "21.00.00",
    "wednesday_open_time": " 07.00.00"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> BufferedReader br = null;
> List<Student> objLst = new ArrayList<Student>();
> InputStreamReader inStreamReader = null;
> inStreamReader = new 
> InputStreamReader(ReadAccountsUtil.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("someFile.csv"));
> CsvReader csvReader = new CsvReader(inStreamReader);
> String objStr[] = {};
> JavaPojoClass id = new Id();
>
>     try {
>         while (csvReader.readRecord()) {
>
>             objStr = csvReader.getRawRecord().split(",");
>             student = new Student();
>             student.setRollNo(new Short(objStr[0]));
>             student.setName(new String(objStr[1]));
>             student.setAdd(new String(objStr[2]));
>             student.setEmail(new String(objStr[3]));
>             objLst.add(student);
>         }
>     } catch (Exception ex) {
>         if(inStreamReader != null){
>             try {
>                 inStreamReader.close();
>             } catch (IOException e) {
>                 LOGGER.error("Error in closing the input streams"+ e.getMessage());
>             }
>         }
>         LOGGER.error("Error in reading the Student file"+ ex.getMessage());
>     }
>     return objLst;
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
 String fileName = "c:\\test.csv";
 char separator = ';';

 List<TestDTO> obj= new CsvToBeanBuilder(new 
 FileReader(fileName)).withSeparator(separator)
                .withType(TestDTO.class)
                .build()
                .parse();

        obj.forEach(System.out::println);

}


import com.opencsv.bean.CsvBindByName;
import lombok.*;

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString

public class TestDTO {
  @CsvBindByName(column = "EXTERNAL_ID")
  private String externalId;
  @CsvBindByName(column = "ID_TYPE")
  private String idType;
  @CsvBindByName(column = "STUDY_ID")
  private String studyId;
  @CsvBindByName(column = "STUDY_NAME")
  private String studyName;
```

}

> pom.xml

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
  <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
  <version>5.3</version>
</dependency>
```

For more details, please visit [openscv](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/#reading_into_beans)